# Python Sockets TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not int

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

Depending on how I decide to send the packet, it "changes" the type. For example, I'll do clientsocket.sendto(str.encode(packet), server_address) but it says it does not expect an int...
It sounds crazy, but I'll post my code to show what's happening.

```
        print(type(packet))
        print(type(encoded_packet))
        print(type(packet.encode('utf-8')))
        server_address = (host, port)
        print(type(server_address))
        clientsocket.sendto(packet.encode('utf-8'), server_address)
```

I receive an error that states

```
TypeError: str, bytes or bytesarray expected, not int
```

This confuses me, because I have

```
print(type(packet.encode('utf-8')))
```

outputting it as

```
<class 'bytes'>
```

So I decided to change it to

```
encoded_packet = str.encode(packet)
clientsocket.sendto(str.encode(encoded_packet), server_address))
```

And receive this... (I know the 2 lines of code above is wrong, I just want to see what it outputs)

```
TypeError: descriptor 'encode' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'bytes' object
```

So... I change it to

```
clientsocket.sendto(encoded_packet, server_address)
```

and receive this error!!!

```
TypeError: str, bytes, or bytearray expected, not int
```

This has been frustrating, any help will be greatly appreciated. I've tried many different combinations, but at the end it "changes" the type.
Thank you for taking the time reading this

EDIT: Output of the first block is

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'tuple'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./netster.py", line 118, in <module>
    main()
  File "./netster.py", line 100, in main
    run_client(args.host, int(args.port), udp=args.udp, rudp=args.rudp, filename=args.file) 
  File "./netster.py", line 46, in run_client
    rdt_send(port, port, kwargs['filename'])
  File "/Users/username/networks_repo/src/py/a3.py", line 234, in rdt_send
    clientsocket.sendto(packet.encode('utf-8'), server_address)
TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not int
```

Comment: What is the type of `clientsocket`? And could you output the live prints from the first code block. I tried it locally and it worked.

Comment: The type of  ```clientsocket``` is ```<class 'socket.socket'>```. I edited the original post to show the output of the first block of code.

Comment: Just to check, are you trying to send the packet as UDP?

Comment: Can you just check the type of your host object?

Comment: Your main issue seems to be `rdt_send(port, port, kwargs['filename'])`. The `port` is passed twice. Maybe you meant to write `rdt_send(host, port, kwargs['filename'])`?

Comment: Thank you Abdou, you are correct. By changing it to rdt_send(host, port, kwargs['filename']), that fixed the issued. I was too focused on the other part of the code to notice that small error.